# Regex for Name - Capitalization and No Special Characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to validate names which are written only in English alphabets. Other special letters such as ç, é, etc. are excluded.

My requirements are:

1. Every word should start with a capital letter (Peter Svidler)
2. A single word should not have two capital letters (PEter Svidler must fail)
3. No digits are allowed. (Peter Svidler9 or Peter 9 Svidler should fail)
4. No special characters are allowed. (Peter Svidler. or Peter S.vidler must fail)
5. Cases to be matched:
   a. R G S Devan or Achar K K S R (allow as many capitalized initials as possible either at the start or at the end)
   b. One word or more than one word (Chandra, Chandra Shekhar Raju, ...)

I tried to validate through 2 expressions

```
\b[A-Z].*?\b
```

and

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

But it is matching for PEter SVidler, or PETER SVIDLER.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind your requirement I came up with [this regex.](https://regex101.com/r/qR0jA9/1)

**Regex**: `\b[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z])?\b`

**Explanation**:

`[A-Z][a-z]*` matches the first name, first character is capital and rest of them small which could be `0 or many` followed by a space.

`[A-Z][a-z]*` matches the surname or middle name, same as first name.

`( [A-Z])?` matches the optional last name as in `Botvinnik M M` or `Vivekanand P V`

Surrounded by `\b` to allow boundary. You can either use anchoring if that's what you need.

Comment: Updated your's to show the captured groups: https://regex101.com/r/qR0jA9/2 (+1 for your solution).

Answer (score 1):

Building on the idea of @noob, I have come up with this:

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*)*\b
```

It matches:

1. John D E F W
2. D E S Matthew
3. Alladi Krishna Swami Aiyar
4. Raja Ravi Varma M
5. A B C D E F

Match case 5 is the only fly in the ointment. I presume given the requirements, it cannot be prevented by the RegEx. I am thinking of tokenizing the input string once it passes the RegEx and examining the string length in the validator method.

Am I missing something?

I have tested this RegEx [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of:

```
not_this|forget_this|nevermind_this|(but_keep_this)
```

So you could come up with:

```
^(?:\b[a-z]|\b[A-Z]{2,})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^([A-Za-z ]+)$
```

See a [regex demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tE6fY1/4)

Comment: Use of `\w` allows `_` to be matched too. `\s` will allow other `whitespaces` too so use single space. Better use `[A-Z]` because the requirement is of capital **only**.

Comment: Seems like you replaced only `\w` where as you also need to replace `\s` with only a `space`. Because `\s` allows line breaks too.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((\b[A-Z][a-z]{1,15})\s*){2,15}$
```

Works for

- Foysal Ahmed Emon
- Foysal Ahmed

Does not work for

- foysal Ahmed
- Emon
- E Ahmed